How do I calculate the parametrization of a 3D surface given its support function?
The support function $h_S$ of a non-empty, closed, convex set $S$ in $ℝ^n$ describes the distances of supporting hyperplanes of $S$ from the origin. A supporting hyperplane is a hyperplane that has both of the following two properties:

$S$ is entirely contained in one of the two closed half-spaces bounded by the hyperplane (where a "closed half-space" is the half-space that includes the points within the hyperplane), and
$S$ has at least one boundary-point on the hyperplane.

In 2D $\left(ℝ^2\right)$, the hyperplanes are lines and $S$ is a curve in the $xy$-plane (or the complex plane, depending on how you want to handle things). In the $xy$-plane we can parametrize a curve with two real functions as $S(θ) = (x(θ), y(θ))$. Given a support function $h_S(θ)$, the two parametric functions which describe $S$ are
$$
x(θ) = \cos(θ) ⋅ h_S(θ) - \sin(θ) ⋅ h_S'(θ) \\
y(θ) = \sin(θ) ⋅ h_S(θ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ h_S'(θ)
$$
the supporting line for a given $θ$ has the equation
$$
\cos(θ) ⋅ x + \sin(θ) ⋅ y = h_S(θ).
$$
and the focal set can be parametrized as
$$
x_f(θ) = -\sin(θ) ⋅ h_S'(θ) - \cos(θ) ⋅ h_S''(θ), \\
y_f(θ) =  \cos(θ) ⋅ h_S'(θ) - \sin(θ) ⋅ h_S''(θ)
$$
Similarly, in the complex plane we can parametrize the curve with a single complex function, as
$$
S(θ) = \bigl(h_S(θ) + i ⋅ h_S'(θ)\bigr) ⋅ e^{i ⋅ θ}.
$$
A pattern I noticed:

The basic parametrization of a circle is $\left(\cos(θ) ⋅ r, \sin(θ) ⋅ r\right)$, which corresponds to the terms in the supporting line and to the first term in the equations for $S$ with the radius term replaced with $h_S(θ)$.
The second term in the equations for $S$ (and the first term in the equations for the focal set of $S$) is the product of the derivatives of the two parts of the first term (but not the derivative of the first term as a whole).
The next term in the equations for the focal set is again the product of the derivatives of the two parts of the previous term.

How do I do the same thing in 3D?
Given a support function in spherical-coordinate variables $h_S(θ, φ)$, I know the equation of the supporting plane is
$$
\sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ) ⋅ x + \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ) ⋅ y + \cos(θ) ⋅ z = h_S(θ, φ).
$$
Based on the way the 2D version works, I'm looking for something along the lines of
$$
x(θ, φ) = \sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ) ⋅ h_S(θ, φ) + [...] \\
y(θ, φ) = \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ) ⋅ h_S(θ, φ) + [...] \\
z(θ, φ) = \cos(θ) ⋅ h_S(θ, φ) + [...]
$$
where the ellipses are replaced with partial derivatives of $h_S(θ, φ)$ with respect to $θ$ and $φ$, combined with some mixture of sines and cosines of the coordinate variables.
But how exactly do they get combined? I've tried to find instructions online and, when that failed, reason it out myself, but the variations I've tried haven't worked. I've found combinations that work when one of the input-variables is fixed at specific angles (essentially reducing it to a curve embedded in 3D space), but nothing that works for the entire surface.

I deleted my answer, because it would be too much effort to write it in a way that you would be able to use it.

@Deane could you Undelete your answer please? OP isn't necessarily the only beneficiary of this discussion :)

@rych, MathFont’s answer looks good to me.

@rych, I've undeleted my answer.

I'm wondering. Are you under any kind of time pressure? Trying to do this without knowing any multivariable calculus is quite difficult, and it's quite difficult for any of us to help you effectively. Any chance you'd be willing to spend a couple of months studying the first (easier) half of a multivariable calculus text?

@Deane There's no time pressure. I've self-taught myself some of the bare basics of multivariable calculus already for this project, but you and MathFont seem to be relying on much more advanced concepts that appear neigh-impenetrable from my current perspective.

From my perspective, we're all using only basic concepts from the first half of a multivariable calculus course since no integration is involved. For example, the partial derivatives and gradient of a function, $\nabla f$, and the chain rule are taught near the start of the course. So maybe "bare basics" isn't enough, but I suggest a month or two of serious effort to learn more might be enough.

If $\vec u$ is a unit vector on the sphere and $h(\vec u)$ is the support function in that direction, then the expression $\vec p(u) = h(\vec u) \vec u + \nabla _S h(u)$  provides a  parametrized surface that fits your requirements. Here $\nabla _S h$ refers to the gradient of $h$ when regarded as a function on the sphere.
Preliminary remarks
Here are additional details on how to compute $\vec p$ using only Cartesian coordinate vector calculus methods.
We claim that $p=\nabla f$ for some suitably chosen function $f$, which is defined below.

One can identify  $h(u)$ with $H( x)$, a homogeneous function of degree 0 in the usual 3D  Cartesian spatial coordinates. (These spatial coordinates will be denoted by  the vector $ x$.) Since the support function $h(u)$ is the same under the antipodal map action on $\vec u$, we have $H(x)= H(-x)$.

Consider the scalar expression $ f(x)=H(x) ||x||$. It is homogeneous of degree 1.

The first-order partial derivatives of $f$ are therefore homogeneous of one lower degree (degree  0).
That is, the  vector quantity $\nabla f$  (the usual Euclidean gradient vector) has the property that its Cartesian components are homogeneous of degree 0.

Expand out $\nabla f$ using the product rule and the fact that $\nabla ||x|| =x/||x|| =\vec u$ is the unit radial vector field.  Then  use the fact that the radial directional derivative of $f$ is $\nabla f \cdot u$, and regard $\nabla H$ as the gradiant of a function that lives on the sphere.

Note that the radial directional derivative of $H$ is zero, so $\nabla H$ is perpendicular to the radial unit vector $ u$.


Thus $\nabla f$ splits as the orthogononal sum of two components: a radial part and a tangential part. This splitting is what we denoted above by $ \vec p= h(\vec u) \vec u+ \nabla _S h $.
Checking the geometric properties of the parametrized surface.
Note that the radial component of $\vec p$ extends outward a distance $h$; that is,  $\vec p\cdot u= h$.  (By symmetry it extends an equal amount in the opposite direction).  This is one of the features that you want your parametrized surface to have (after you scale down the surface by a factor 1/2, replacing $f$ by $f/2$ in all of the above).
To verify that your parametrized surface has the property its tangent plane is perpendicular to $\vec u$ at $\vec p(\vec u)$ is more involved, since you have to take more derivatives. I leave that to you to verify.
Answer to your original question
Problem.  Compute the parametrized position vector of points on your surface $\vec p$ using spherical coordinates, starting with $h(\theta, \phi)$ as known.
Solution.
$\vec p= h \vec u + \nabla_S h $ where
(1) The unit vector $u$ is the  position vector  on unit sphere.
(2)  $\nabla_S h= h_{\theta} \nabla \theta + h_{\phi} \nabla \phi$
in which $h_{\theta}$ and $h_{\phi}$ denote partial derivatives of $h$.
(3) The expression $\nabla \theta =<\theta_x, \theta_y, \theta_z>$  and likewise $\nabla _\phi$ can be read off from the  partial derivative formulas pictured below ( with the caution  that the symbols $\theta$ and $\phi$ trade places when physicists and mathematicians  talk about spherical coordinates.
Details are here: physics formula for spherical gradients
]2

Deane is right. Can you explain what you mean by "the gradient of $h$ when regarded as a function on the sphere" and how to convert it to functions $\bigl(x(θ, φ), y(θ, φ), z(θ, φ)\bigr)$?

I'm still not understanding how to get Cartesian equations from your answer. Is it possible to explain this without using vector calculus?

I was able to verify that the equations in the image you added can be combined into the parametrization I'm after. Thank you! I'll work on understanding the post you linked for how they are derived.

Here is one way to do this:
The support function $h$ of a convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a function of $u \in S^{n-1}$. You can extend $h$ to be a homogeneous function $H: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,\infty)$
by setting $$H(x) = |x|h\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right). $$
If the support function is $C^2$ and $\partial K$ has positive definite second fundamental form, then the map
\begin{align*} S^{n-1} &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\\ u &\mapsto (\partial_1H(u), \dots, \partial_nH(u)) \end{align*} is a parameterization of $\partial K$.

Can you be a bit more descriptive/explicit? I don't understand the notation you've used, not even enough to know what to search for in order to find an explanation.

Which notation?

$\Phi: S^{n-1} \rightarrow \partial K$ and $\Phi(u) = \nabla H(u)$, for a start.

I've edited my answer, but to be honest, it's now aimed for people who are familiar with the notation. I think @MathFont's answer is more likely to be useful to you if you're able to get more details about the notation.
